# Why a inconsistent system can be considered as a span? (updated, example added)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have some problems in learning about span.
The definition of $\operatorname{span}\{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3\}=$ all linear combinations of $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3$.

However, when I deal with question like asking a given vector where it is inside the span of given vector $\{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v}_3\}$. I try to solve it as a system $\begin{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&\vec{v}_2&\vec{v}_3\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}t_1&t_2&t_3\end{bmatrix}^T=v$.
I found the system is inconsistent, but $v$ is still an element of $\operatorname{span}\{\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,\vec{v_3}\}$, why?

an example:

[image]

Comment: Can you give an actual example of what you mean?

Comment: Please edit the question to show your actual work for the particular vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ and $v$.

Comment: To say that the system you got is "inconsistent" **means** that the system of equation [b]cannot[/b] be satisfied and, in the case of vectors, that the given set of vectors does NOT span the space Please show us the particular example in which you believe this is not true.

Comment: To be clear, I'd say that the span was the collection of all vectors which can be written as linear combinations of the given vectors.  That is slightly different from what you wrote.  If your vectors are linearly dependent then a given vector ($\vec 0$ for one) can be written in multiple ways but it only counts once in the span.

Comment: I would assume that there is a typo in the figure, and they meant $\not\in$ as opposed to $\in$

Comment: @Wouter Please post your comment as an answer. The vector in question is _not_ in the span.

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is in the span of the set you mentioned, then it is expressible as a linear combination of vectors in the original set. This linear combination solves the equation you say is "inconsistent".

If what you mean by "inconsistent" is that a matrix made of the $v_i$ has zero determinant, this simply expresses the fact that they are linearly dependent, and that they will span a space of fewer than $3$ dimensions. But the span still exists. If $v_1\neq 0$ then $v_1$ is definitely in the span, for example.

Answer (score -1):

the only v is in the span {v1, v2, v3} if the system you mentioned is *consistent*. Not sure if your last sentence is true.

Answer (score -1):

cps01hkt is right, the figure is wrong, $\mathbf{v}$ is not an element of the span of ${\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3}$.